# Detect if Mac browser is running in 32 or 64-bit mode

Tags: javascript, macos

How do you detect if a browser on Mac is running in 32 or 64 bit mode? With the advent of Snow Leopard, browser developers such as Firefox and Safari have been pushing everyone towards 64 bit browsing. Unfortunately, my website uses a plugin that only works in 32 bit mode. I would like to detect when Firfox 4 or Safari 5 is running in 64 bit mode, so I can display the proper error message. Using Javascript woud be ideal.